# How do I setup WebSocket server for tTPC when using Next.js v13 app router?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to add WebSocket server to my Next.js v13 app/ router.

https://trpc.io/docs/subscriptions

However, I am not clear where should this code go.

I have found an example for pages/ router, but the patterns do not seem to be transferable to app/ router.